# Handling R error: in rep(value[[k]], length.out = n) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to plot a chi-squared against a normal distribution. I am getting the following error, and I am not sure why: 
"in rep(value[[k]], length.out = n) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'"

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(10204)

mu = 0
sd = 1
norm_df <- tibble(X = seq(1, 10, 1), 
                  Z = dnorm(x = X, mu, sd))
chi_df <- tibble(Xseq = seq(1, 10, 1), 
                 X = dchisq(x = Xseq, df = 1))

ggplot(data = norm_df, aes(x = X)) + 
  geom_histogram(y = stat(density), binwidth = 1) + 
  geom_line(data = chi_df, aes(x = Xseq - 0.5, y = X))
```

I am hoping to get a plot to deliver, with the chi-squared being the line on the distribution and the frequency count of the normal being a histogram.

Comment: Your error is in the `geom_histogram` call. You probably want `aes(y = ..density..)`.

Comment: The `y = stat(density)` code should be inside `aes()`.